Custom Riemann solver
I have written my own Riemann solver for a specific problem.
Unfortunately, I am unable to update the solution over time and create a simulation using PyClaw. I am quite new to PyClaw and have tried many things, but unfortunately, nothing seems to work. Do you see anything that I might have done wrong? Is there perhaps
something wrong with my Riemann solver?
This is my Riemann solver (for the scalar advection equation, but with 3rd order accuracy; That is why I can't just import a Riemman solver that already exists):
def rp1(maxmx, meqn, mwaves, maux, mbc, mx, ql, qr, auxl, auxr, wave, s, amdq, apdq):
    u = 0.5  
    dx = 1.0 / mx 
    for i in range(2 - mbc, mx + mbc):
        if u > 0:
            q_i = ql[0, i]
            q_ip1 = ql[0, i+1]
            q_im1 = ql[0, i-1]
            q_x = (q_ip1 - q_i) / dx
            q_xx = (q_ip1 - 2 * q_i + q_im1) / dx**2
            
            q_ip12 = q_i + 0.5 * (q_ip1 - q_i) - (1/6) * (q_im1 - 2 * q_i + q_ip1)
            wave[0, 0, i] = q_ip12 - q_i
        else:
            q_i = qr[0, i]
            q_ip1 = qr[0, i+1]
            q_ip2 = qr[0, i+2] if i + 2 < maxmx + mbc else qr[0, i+1]
            q_x = (q_ip1 - q_i) / dx
            q_xx = (q_ip2 - 2 * q_ip1 + q_i) / dx**2
            
            q_im12 = q_ip1 - 0.5 * (q_ip1 - q_i) - (1/6) * (q_ip2 - 2 * q_ip1 + q_i)
            wave[0, 0, i] = q_i - q_im12
        s[0, i] = u
        
        amdq[0, i] = min(u * wave[0, 0, i], 0)
        apdq[0, i] = max(u * wave[0, 0, i], 0)
    return wave, s, amdq, apdq 

This should be my main simulation (as a picture)
I would really appreciate any tips.
